# Падает программа: неинициализированная переменная

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!

Делаю упражнение из K&R, и встал в одном месте. При вызове функции, программа падает (компилируется в VS 2010 успешно) и пишет, что переменная farh не инициализированная. Код после совета (все равно падает):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int temperature(int farh);

main()
{
    char c;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");    
    printf("Температураn Фаренгейта t Цельсияn");    
    c = getchar();    
    temperature(c);    
    system("pause");
}

int temperature(int farh)
{
    return (5.0 / 9.0) * (farh - 32);
}
```

Подскажите, где я промахнулся? Я думал, что с типом перепутал, и делал вначале с double, потом с float, ну а потом принудительно (когда int, как сейчас) приравнивал к `(double)`

Спасибо.

Comment: Могу сказать, что в функции temperature в аргументах **FARH**, а внутри **FAHR**. Я не сишник, мож еще чего не вижу, но мобыть поможет им при ответе.

Comment: Интересные дела творятся в VS 2010. 

Я попробовал (Copy/Paste) в MinGW gcc. Температуру она **конечно же** не выводит (это видимо задумано, но не реализовано), но отрабатывает в окошке командной строки без причуд. 

Никто ни на что не ругается. 

--

Какими инструментами пользоваться - решать Вам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float temperature(float farh);

int main()
{
    float c, f;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    scanf("%f", &c);
    f = temperature(c);
    printf("Температура\n Фаренгейта t= %f\n Цельсия t =%f\n", c,f);
    system("pause");
}

float temperature(float farh)
{
    return (5.0 / 9.0) * (farh - 32);
}
```

Вот такой код компилится нормально в студии 2010.
И вообще, как мне кажется, последняя версия, поддерживающая чистый СИ -  MS VS 6.
Поставьте Code::Blocks . Сам в нём по К&R задачки делаю :)

Comment: Чтобы совсем хорошо было, следует добавить `return 0;` или `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` в конце функции main. В противном случае в ОС возвращается неопределенное значение в качестве кода возврата.

Comment: Mikola, я про scanf знаю, просто, пока в упражнении надо использовать getchar. Впринципе, из-за него и вся ошибка.

Comment: "Использовать getchar()" - это означает, что надо прочесть число (возможно с десятичной точкой) **символ за символом**. Потом (или по ходу чтения) преобразовать его (эти символы) в float (число в машинном формате) и потом вызвать temperature().

Ну и не забыть вывести результат.

--

Про подобные ограничения (использовать getchar()) надо предупреждать сразу, в вопросе, а то не понятно, что у Вас на самом деле не получается.

Answer (score 2):

В функции temperature() локальная переменная farh перекрывает формальный параметер farh. Удалите ее. Код функции будет таким:

```
int temperature(int farh)
{
    return (5.0/9.0)*(farh-32);
}
```

из функции main() переменную fahr тоже можно удалить, т.к. там она нигде не используется:)

Comment: Определение `int farh` следует вообще убрать.

Comment: Собственно об этом писал в ответе, а в коде забыл убрать. Все подправил:)

Comment: Не помогло, всёравно падает по той же причине!

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я помню СИ, int деленный на int будет 0, и соответственно int функция вернет целое

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <locale.h>

float temperature(float farh);

int main()
{
    float c, f;

//    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");    
    scanf("%f", &c);    
    f = temperature(c); 
    printf("Температура\n Фаренгейта t= %f\n Цельсия t =%f\n", c,f);

//    system("pause");
}

float temperature(float farh)
{
    return (5.0 / 9.0) * (farh - 32.0);
}
```

Comment: Странно, если писать(по условиям K&R я ещё scanf не знаю, хотя я знаю) так:
main()
{
 double c,f;
  
 setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS"); 
 
 c = getchar();
 f = temperature(c);

 printf("Температура\n по Фаренгейту: %f \n по Цельсию %f\n",c,f);
 
 system("pause");
}

double temperature(double farh)
{
    return (5.0/9.0)*(farh-32.0);
}

ТО температура получается в 2 раза меньше правильной.

Comment: getchar() считывает с клавиатуры символ, в переменную c попадает ее код. Так что если с клавиатуры введено 0, то в c оказывается 48, что по Цельсию равно почти 9 градусов.

Answer (score 0):

fahr объявлена и не инициализирована значением. Может Вы имели ввиду farh?

Comment: Нет, это бональная опечатка.